# Websphere Startup Error

Tags: workspace, websphere-7

I am trying to  set up workspace using Websphere 7.0 application server on RAD IDE. I am using Java 1.6

When ever i try to start my server it throws following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
Could not find the main class: Files.  Program will exit.
```

What would be reason for this? Did anyone get this kind of error before.

Note: I tried googling out and people suggest try changing classpath, which i tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something, somewhere is failing to quote an argument containing C:\Program Files, probably due to custom JVM configuration.  If you use the -script option to bin\startServer.bat, you might be able to determine where things are going wrong.  This might be a product issue, so if you can't figure it out (or you don't think your configuration is to blame), then you might consider opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Thank you bkail. I figured out the error and reason is in the xml.properties files the class path was having an an extra '/'. Thanks.

Comment: "Program Files" missing quotes somewhere does seem to be the ultimate cause of this error. In my case, it was because I had set a Windows `JAVA_HOME` environment variable without quotes for another reason, and for some reason the WebSphere `setupCmdLine.bat` file now has commented out its own `set JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue when trying to start the server from RAD console , this might be a product issue , a quick way to solve this might be to start the server using command line see below example on how to start the server

C:\WorkFolder\WASV8.5_Install\profiles\AppSrv03\bin>startServer.bat server1 -profileName AppSrv02

Try to start in an command prompt you would see the servers starting in your RAD console as well.

```
       C:\WorkFolder\WASV8.5_Install\profiles\AppSrv02\logs\server1\startServer.log
```

ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv02 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
ADMU3000I: Server server1 open for e-business; process id is 20484